# How to connect to analysis services from external internet

Tags: ssas, ssms

Basically, This is the first question i'm raising on stackoverflow. Also I'm a beginner of SSAS and encounter a remote connection problem.

SCENARIO:

An analysis services instance with the default name has been built on Server-A. Settings on port numbers have been done on both Server-A firewall and the related router.

Let's say we have PC-A within the local network as Server-A. The fact is that I start the Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS) by run as another user name (log in via Server-A\username), and the connection can be successfully built up by entering the local IP address for Server-A.

QUESTION:

Assuming having a PC-B which is NOT within the same local network as Server-A, what should I do with SSMS to connect to the AS databases on Server-A from PC-B ? Is there any similar way like that for PC-A?

Thanks in advance!

Zhiwei

Answer (score 1):

This is a complicated question and depends on a lot of additional information. Perhaps a good place to start is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx).